# Node.js and Socket.io - Certificate is invalid

Tags: node.js, socket.io, openssl, lets-encrypt

I'm having trouble connecting my chat application to Node.js server running on Ubuntu 16.04. The problem seems to be the ssl certificate which have been generated using 'letsencrypt'.

I have successfully connected to my Node.js server using a openssl certificate - this however only works in my Chrome browser.

Here is my code for the Node.js part.:

```
let fs = require('fs');
let https = require('https');

var options = {
     key: fs.readFileSync('./file.pem'),
     cert: fs.readFileSync('./file.crt')
};

let server = https.createServer(options);
let io = require('socket.io')(server);

let Redis = require('ioredis');
let redis = new Redis();

redis.subscribe('all-chat');

redis.on('message', function (channel, message) {
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});

server.listen(3201);
```

The error code I'm getting from my browser is.:

```
net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

My guess is that for some odd reason the certificates I have obtained is not following a standard of some sorts, so the browser discards the response.

For what I can gather around the web about this problem - the solution should be using a certificate from 'letsencrypt' and/or multiple variations of.:

```
var options = { ... };
```

And I do believe I have tried every possible combination.

If I open my website in two windows, one in Edge and one in Chrome, I can succesfully send a message from Edge to Chrome - the message will however not be shown in Edge as it should.

Thanks in advance for any detail that may put me back on track!

Answer (score 1):

The answer was rather simple. To be sure you can use your certificate you can use the diagnostic tool found on https://www.digicert.com/help/.

For the connection from client to my Node.js end I stated the IP on the client side - and that will not do when using a certificate which have been created with the public domain. So I changed the IP on the client side from the IP to the public domain and it worked!